# Sharepoint Library Corruption

Tags: 2013, document-library

I am experiencing an odd issue with my SharePoint 2013 environment. Running on RTM  prior to putting the system in production, I was letting my users fiddle around with an SP site. They had edit rights to the site and were not SC admins. I got a call saying that they could not access most of the documents they had uploaded.

Upon investigation, I found that the list did not have any views listed as available (not even the default) and would 404 if clicked on in the Site Contents list. I could still access the "allitems" view by putting in the full path, but even viewing that showed very few files. By comparison, the Site Content list showed over 60 files. SharePoint designer similarly showed the same handful of files.

Delving into the database, I can find that the files continue to exist, have content in the content field, and correctly show the path to the list. This leads me to believe that the list item itself is corrupted. Is this something others have experienced before and how can the library be recovered to a functioning state? I'm currently patching to the Dec '13 hotfix in case that helps, but none of the notes on any of the fixes that I could find even came close to this problem.

This is my first post on Stack Exchange, so please forgive me if I'm asking this question in the wrong place or in the wrong style. Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AHA! There were actually 2 mysteries here which likely lead to my trouble figuring this out. Nothing was actually corrupted, just an inexperienced user and an inexperienced admin coupled with some slightly strange behavior in SP.

The first mystery, that of the phantom files, was caused by SharePoint marking most of the uploaded files as checked out to a user, but without any checked in version. SP did not show them, but it did count them in the ItemCount property of the library. My understanding at this point is that this was caused by bulk uploading of files through explorer.

The second mystery, I'm still a little confused by. The original "AllItems" view actually existed in the library's views collection, but it had been marked as hidden and the title had been blanked. I'm not sure how the user set it as a hidden view from the UI (I haven't yet found the button to do that), but I was able to restore the view by setting the hidden property to false and assigning a title to it. The invalid URL listed in the library if there are no visible views I'm guessing is a bug, especially given that the cancel button in the library properties redirected me to a totally different site collection, but at least it's easy enough to remediate.

Hopefully this information will help the next confused SP rookie admin to try to avoid thinking SP has gone completely off the rails.